# How to lock file for another threads

Tags: java, concurrency, filechannel, filelock

This is my method that compresses file into archive:

```
public void addFilesToArchive(File source, File destination) throws 
IOException, ArchiveException {

    try (FileOutputStream archiveStream = new FileOutputStream(destination);
          ArchiveOutputStream archive = new ArchiveStreamFactory()
                  .createArchiveOutputStream(getType(), archiveStream)) {

        updateSourceFolder(source);
        generateFileAndFolderList(source);

        for (String entryName : fileList) {
            ArchiveEntry entry = getEntry(entryName);
            archive.putArchiveEntry(entry);
            archive.closeArchiveEntry();
        }
    }
}
```

fileList conatains all file hierarchy (folder and files)

I want to prevent compressing from different threads into one destination at the same time.

Try to use:

```
FileChannel channel = archiveStream.getChannel();
channel.lock();
```

but it doesn't seem to be helpful. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to lock the file against other *threads,* not other processes, and this is exactly what file locks don't do. See the Javadoc. You need to use synchronization or semaphores.